# Meebo Me replacement

Tags: widget, google-talk, msn-messenger, windows-live-messenger, meebo

With the recent Meebo acquiring by Google Meebo Me widget is also gone.

I would like to have similar functionality. Something which I can put on my web site and allow guest users to chat to me on my MSN (Live) or Gtalk messenger I have on my computer. It may also be Skype if it has something like that.

Up until now I was using Google TalkBack badge which stopped functioning (it just loads http://support.google.com page). Then I used MeeboMe widget which had similar functionality athough I had to run MeeboMe notifier. Now that is gone too. I tried Plugoo which also works, but sometime buddy_plugoo which I added as contact is offline and then the web widget also shows me as "offline" even though I am not so it is not really reliable.

I also have 2 gmail accounts and tried to connect to one via XMPP.php and send a message to other one - but it won't even connect. Tried various examples. I could use one "dump" gmail account to chat with my main account if this would be able to connect and create a web-interface.

So do you know of some alternative widget for websites? Something that I could connect to my desktop messengers and chat to website visitors so that when visitor writes a message it pops up in my messenger. I could also write my own app given that it is not something too time consuming - I need only basic notification when visitor writes a message and chat with him/her. Preferably free one.